# SequelizeConnectionError in Node.js application

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, docker, sequelize.js

I have strange problem and don't know in what place is the problem. I will be grateful for any help.

I have **Node.js** application which works fine in local windows 10 computer. I run this application successfully in **Docker** which is in CentOS server. This application works with remote MySQL and PostgreSQL databases. It worked correctly several days but yestoday I notice that I have error. Application can't connect to remote MySQL database anymore. In the same time I can connect to that remote MySQL database without any problem if I run application in my local computer or connect by DBeaver/dbForge tool.

**MySQL.js**:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('database_name', 'username', 'password', {
    host: 'host',
    dialect: 'mysql'
});

sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
    console.log('Connection to database has been established successfully.');
}).catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to database:', err);
});

module.exports = sequelize;
```

**routes.js**:

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

const sequelize = require('../configurations/MySQL');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const passport = require('passport');
require('../configurations/password')(passport);

router.post('/search_by_name', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}, null), function(req, res) {
    const token = getToken(req.headers);
    if (token) {
        sequelize.query("LONG SQL QUERY", {
            replacements: {
                name: req.body.name,
            },
            type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
        }).then((locations) => {
            res.status(200).send(locations)
        }).catch((error) => {
            res.status(400).send(error);
        });
    } else {
        return res.status(401).send({
            status: false,
            description: "Unauthorized"
        });
    }
});
```

As you can see I use [sequelize](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/v3/) library to connect application to remote MySQL database. The same library I use to connect to remote PostgreSQL database. As I said before error happens only when I try to connect to remote MySQL database in Docker. There is no error with PostgreSQL connection in Docker. Is it possible that problem inside Docker/network?

**Dependencies**:

```
"sequelize": "^4.42.0"
"mysql2": "^1.6.4"
```

I also thought that the reason of the problem can be because of much pools/connections and sequelize library don't close them automatically. For thats why I restarted docker сontainer several times hoping to confirm the theory. Unfortunately the error do not disappear.

How do you think, what happens?

**Error**:

```
Unable to connect to the database: { SequelizeConnectionError: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at Utils.Promise.tap.then.catch.err (/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:149:19)
    at tryCatcher (/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:690:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
    at _drainQueue (/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:632:19)
  name: 'SequelizeConnectionError',
  parent:
   { Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
       at Connection._handleTimeoutError (/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:173:17)
       at listOnTimeout (timers.js:324:15)
       at processTimers (timers.js:268:5)
     errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
     code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
     syscall: 'connect',
     fatal: true },
  original:
   { Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
       at Connection._handleTimeoutError (/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:173:17)
       at listOnTimeout (timers.js:324:15)
       at processTimers (timers.js:268:5)
     errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
     code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
     syscall: 'connect',
     fatal: true }}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to add pool option when new Sequelize. Reference [document](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/installation/getting-started.html#setting-up-a-connection)

> Sequelize will setup a connection pool on initialization so you should
>   ideally only ever create one instance per database if you're
>   connecting to the DB from a single process. If you're connecting to
>   the DB from multiple processes, you'll have to create one instance per
>   process, but each instance should have a maximum connection pool size
>   of "max connection pool size divided by number of instances". So, if
>   you wanted a max connection pool size of 90 and you had 3 worker
>   processes, each process's instance should have a max connection pool
>   size of 30.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('database_name', 'username', 'password', {
    host: 'host',
    dialect: 'mysql',
    pool: {
      max: 15,
      min: 5,
      idle: 20000,
      evict: 15000,
      acquire: 30000
    },
});

module.exports = sequelize;
```

Also, you can check more option at [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#instance-constructor-constructor)

> **options.pool**   sequelize connection pool configuration
>
> **options.pool.max**  default: 5 Maximum number of connection in pool
>
> **options.pool.min**  default: 0 Minimum number of connection in pool
>
> **options.pool.idle**  default: 10000 The maximum time, in milliseconds,
>   that a connection can be idle before being released. Use with
>   combination of evict for proper working, for more details read
>   https://github.com/coopernurse/node-pool/issues/178#issuecomment-327110870
>
> **options.pool.acquire** default: 10000 The maximum time, in milliseconds,
>   that pool will try to get connection before throwing error
>
> **options.pool.evict** default: 10000 The time interval, in milliseconds,
>   for evicting stale connections. Set it to 0 to disable this feature.
>
> **options.pool.handleDisconnects** default: true Controls if pool should
>   handle connection disconnect automatically without throwing errors
>
> **options.pool.validate** A function that validates a connection. Called
>   with client. The default function checks that client is an object, and
>   that its state is not disconnected

Comment: An hour ago I noticed a new error: `User 'mysql_user' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 20)`. I can use next command `set global max_connections = 200;` and fix that error I think but the reason of the problem is steal relevant. It may appear in the future again. It seems to me that I need to make refactoring. I need to use pool I think and somehow close it after every sql query. What can you advice?

Comment: so do you have any ideas about last my comment?

Answer (score 0):

In the simple terms i want to say that these type of error comes when your some configuration wrong entered. these are :

1. **DB Name**
2. **Username**
3. **Password**

so please cross verify your these things in your **congif.json** file

Answer (score 0):

I  would recommend to check the Database Hostname. Please try to resolve the hostname, if it is given IP address instead of domain. This would resolve the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).