# How to connect my application with MySQL database as a service on oracle cloud infrastructure?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I want to connect my web application which is in development phase to the MySQL database as a service in the oracle cloud infrastructure. Currently, I have been able to configure the MySQL database as a service and I am able to connect to it through the server CLI as well as from Workbench installed on my remote pc and create and query databases from the CLI. The database changes (new db, table creation, updation) are represented in the Workbench as well as any other remote environment that I use to connect to the the database service.

So I believe the database has been correctly deployed. The problem that I am facing right now when I try to connect to the MySQL DBS from within any of my applications is that I get some connection timeout error and I am not able to connect to it from within my code. I am new to this and I am not able to understand the reason behind this. I have spent quite a few days to figure out the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using Sequelize ORM and mysql2

Below is my config.json file for connecting with the remotely deployed database:

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "johndoe",
   "host": "10.0.1.3",
  "dialect": "mysql",
    "password": "Oraclecloud1@",
    "database": "test"
  },
```

host is where MySQL is running on the remote 130.61.183.23 instance address.

Server.js file for setting up the local node js server on my machine to run the application

```
const express=require('express')

const app=express()

app.use(express.json()) 
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}))

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); 
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
  next();
});

var models=require('./models')

models.sequelize.sync().then(function(){
    console.log('Database looks fine')
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log(err,'Something went wrong with the db')
})

require('./routers/index')(app)
port=process.env.PORT || 3003
app.listen(port,console.log('server up'))
```

Index.js file in models

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Below is the timeout error that I get

```
ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: connect ETIMEDOUT    at ConnectionManager.connect (D:\Notes\Node\servertest\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\connection-manager.js:126:17)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async ConnectionManager._connect (D:\Notes\Node\servertest\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:318:24)
    at async D:\Notes\Node\servertest\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:250:32
    at async ConnectionManager.getConnection (D:\Notes\Node\servertest\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:280:7)
    at async D:\Notes\Node\servertest\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:613:26
    at async MySQLQueryInterface.createTable (D:\Notes\Node\servertest\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-interface.js:225:12)
    at async Function.sync (D:\Notes\Node\servertest\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1300:5)
    at async Sequelize.sync (D:\Notes\Node\servertest\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:793:35) {
  parent: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
      at Connection._handleTimeoutError (D:\Notes\Node\servertest\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:178:17)
      at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
      at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7) {
    errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
    code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
    syscall: 'connect',
    fatal: true
  },
  original: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
      at Connection._handleTimeoutError (D:\Notes\Node\servertest\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:178:17)
      at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
      at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7) {
    errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
    code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
    syscall: 'connect',
    fatal: true
  }
} Something went wrong with the db
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking into this it seems that several possible things could be happening including that your DB is not running or that your firewall is not allowing for access. One other thing I've seen includes adding a pool option to your configuration - [SequelizeConnectionError in Node.js application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55134325/sequelizeconnectionerror-in-node-js-application)

Comment: I have checked the DB is running and I can manipulate it using the CLI and workbench. Maybe the firewall is not allowing access to connect with the DB from the code. Can you please guide me how can I set my firewall to allow access? The db can be accessed through the CLI and wrokbench but not from the application code as I earlier mentioned.